# how i can get the result on a display

Tags: javascript, html, input, output

i tried to make form, and i had a problem when i can't get the input from user to display in my web, its make me stressed, i cannot sleep in this week, i already leave my home, i loose my work cause of this. please help me.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <H1>Give me miracle</H1>
        </header>
        <aside class="input">
            <form action="#" id="form">
                <label for="name">Input Your Name here</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
            </form>
        </aside>
        <aside class="output">
            <h1>this is the output</h1>
            <ul id="myUl">
                <li>balls</li>
                <li>dummy</li>
            </ul>
        </aside>    
        <script>
        function out(){
             const pliss = document.getElementById("name").value;
             const show = document.getElementById("myUl");
             const theOutput = document.createElement("li");
    }
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> Use decorations according to your preference

As `submit` is to submit form to server and reload page to the feedback , here `preventDefault();` ignores that way and execute the function  when submit is clicked without executing default function of reloading/open new tab as specified by user in server side language.

**Getting values from input and enter to `id` using specific `id` :**
Here first input value is taken to a `const` which then enter in `id` using `.innerHTML`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <H1>Give me miracle</H1>
  </header>
  <aside class="input">
    <form action="#" id="form">
      <label for="name">Input Your Name here</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" onclick="out(event)">
    </form>
  </aside>
  <aside class="output">
    <h1>this is the output</h1>
    <ul id="myUl">
      <li id="myInput">Input will be here on click of submit</li>
      <li>dummy</li>
    </ul>
  </aside>
  <script>
    function out(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      const pliss = document.getElementById("name").value;
      const show = document.getElementById("myUl");
      const theOutput = document.createElement("li");
      document.getElementById("myInput").innerHTML = pliss;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Getting values from multiple inputs and enter to `id` using specific `id` separately :**
If there are more than 1 input than refer to below snippet , method is almost same as first snippet

```html
<head>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <H1>Give me miracle</H1>
  </header>
  <aside class="input">
    <form action="#" id="form">
      <label for="firsName">Input Your First Name here</label>
      <input type="text" name="firsName" id="firsName">
      <br>
      <label for="lastName">Input Your Last Name here</label>
      <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName">
      <br>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" onclick="out(event)">
    </form>
  </aside>
  <aside class="output">
    <h1>this is the output</h1>
    <ul id="myUl">
      <li id="myInput1">First Input will be here on click of submit</li>
      <li id="myInput2">Second Input will be here on click of submit</li>
    </ul>
  </aside>
  <script>
    function out(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      const pliss1 = document.getElementById("firsName").value;
      const pliss2 = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
      document.getElementById("myInput1").innerHTML = pliss1;
      document.getElementById("myInput2").innerHTML = pliss2;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Getting values from multiple inputs and enter to certain `id` using `for` loop :**
Comments are provided in below snippet

```html
<head>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <H1>Give me miracle</H1>
  </header>
  <aside class="input">
    <form action="#" id="form">
      <label for="firsName">Input Your First Name here</label>
      <input type="text" name="firsName" id="firsName">
      <br>
      <label for="lastName">Input Your Last Name here</label>
      <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName">
      <br>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" onclick="out(event)">
    </form>
  </aside>
  <aside class="output">
    <h1>this is the output</h1>
    <ul id="myUl">
      <li id="myInput1">First Input will be here on click of submit</li>
      <li id="myInput2">Second Input will be here on click of submit</li>
    </ul>
  </aside>
  <script>
    function out(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var inputValue = document.getElementById("form").getElementsByTagName("INPUT")
      //Number of li tags should be equal to number of inputs whose values you want to take
      var inputValueToLi = document.getElementById("myUl").getElementsByTagName("LI")
      //Here length is used 1 less because there are 3 input tags(out of which one is submit)
      for (let i = 0; i < inputValue.length-1; i++) {
      //loop through every values and enter them 
       inputValueToLi[i].innerHTML = inputValue[i].value
       //Here how it is working
       //inputValueToLi[1].innerHTML = inputValue[1].value
       //inputValueToLi[2].innerHTML = inputValue[2].value
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Getting values from input and appending to `li` tag using `.append` method :**
Taken from one [@Sourav Das](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10045841/sourav-das) but in JavaScript way .
Here in below snippet first an `li` element is crated using `.createElement` and value from `input` is taken to `var` whose value is then created as textNode which then entered in created `li` tag using `.appendChild` . This tag is then entered in `ul` tag by using `.appendChild` again .
[Refer to this to know more about following method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createtextnode.asp)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <H1>Give me miracle</H1>
  </header>
  <aside class="input">
    <form action="#" id="form" onsubmit="addtoList(event);">
      <label for="name">Input Your Name here</label>
      <input type="text" id="marvel">
      <input type="submit" value="Add to List">
    </form>
  </aside>
  <aside class="output" id="container">
    <h1>this is the output</h1>
    <ul class="inputApendHere">
      <li>balls</li>
      <li>dummy</li>
    </ul>
  </aside>
  <script>
    function addtoList(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var li = document.createElement("li");
      var inputValue = document.getElementById("marvel").value;
      var t = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
      li.appendChild(t);
      document.querySelector(".inputApendHere").appendChild(li);
      document.querySelector("#marvel").value = "";
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Can someone help me with the thing `this` and `event` difference here in `onclick="out(event)"` and it can be written as `onclick="out(this)"` but here using latter on in the code throws an error

Comment: thank you before, and how if i had more input, should i append it? and how to do that

Comment: You have to get individual values from each `input` and enter them to different `class/id` or use a `for` loop to get values from `input` but you must remember the method here I used is not valid it is only to get values from input , instead a server side execution occur on click of `form` `submit` and page reload or open in new tab with a function runned on `submit`

Comment: You can also try above answer for adding element whenever user enters a value in input it is then appended to `ul` tag and reset back the value back to `""` so value is entered only 1 time but it is not what you may need get values from different inputs .

Comment: whoaa.. thankyou very much. it works... it was a simply code but i didn't know what method to do that before. well now i know it >.<. again again ty very much

Comment: Welcome , if face any issue comment I will try my best

Answer (score -2):

It's simple if you get no input from user instead of letting him procced notify him like:-

```
    <script>
         function out(){
              const pliss = document.getElementById("name").value;
              if(pliss == "" || pliss == null){
                  alert("Please enter your name")
              }
              else{
                  const show = document.getElementById("myUl");
                  const theOutput = document.createElement("li");
              }

         }
   </script>
```

Comment: nah u made it bro, ty very much.

Answer (score -2):

You are not using any JQuery library file or cdn into the  tag.
Down here is the working code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <!-- jQuery CDN link -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <H1>Give me miracle</H1>
    </header>
    <aside class="input">
        <form action="#" id="form" onsubmit="addtoList('marvel');">
            <label for="name">Input Your Name here</label>
            <input type="text" id="marvel">
            <input type="submit" value="Add to List">
        </form>
    </aside>
    <aside class="output" id="container">
        <h1>this is the output</h1>
        <ul>
            <li>balls</li>
            <li>dummy</li>
        </ul>
    </aside>    
    <script>
    function addtoList(id) {

        var temp = $("#"+id).val();
        var newli = '<li>'+temp+'</li>';
        $("#container ul").append(newli);
    }
    </script>
 </body>
```

`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: got it sir, ty for the answer :v